# JSF Updating p:selectOneMenu from another p:selectOneListbox with Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I've been trying to do something that would be really simple... yet it won't work.

I have 2 "p:selectOneMenu", so that the second one items depends on the chosen item in the first one. They both have their own methods in the bean to list their items.

What I wanted to do was when the first changes its value, update the another so that the component should reload the list considering the choosen object. But the ajax never happens, at least in debug the method in the Bean is never called again.

What is wrong? The code is something like...

Thanks!!! :)

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{itemBean.lotacao}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose one" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{itemBean.listLotacoes()}" 
        var="lotacao"
        itemLabel="#{lotacao.format()}" />
    <p:ajax update="localizacaoPorLotacao" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:selectOneMenu id="localizacaoPorLotacao" 
    value="#{itemBean.localizacao}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose one" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{itemBean.listByLotacao(itemBean.lotacao)}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ItemBean {

    // attributes, getters and setters here...

    public List<Lotacao> listLotacoes() {
        LotacaoService lotacaoService = new LotacaoService();  
        List<Lotacao> lotacoes = lotacaoService.getAll();       
        return lotacoes;
    }

    public List<Lotacao> listByLotacao(Lotacao lotacao) {
        if (lotacao == null) {
            return new ArrayList<Lotacao>();
        }

        String prefixo = lotacao.getCodigo().substring(0, 1);
        LotacaoService lotacaoService = new LotacaoService();  
        List<Lotacao> lotacoes = lotacaoService.getByPrefix(prefixo);

        return lotacoes;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

The lack of a converter to the class made the JSF don't trigger the setter.
After creating a converter and adding it to the OneMenu, the code worked just fine.

The final version is:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{itemQuadroVagasBean.lotacao}" 
    converter="orgaoLotacaoCodigoConverter">
    <p:ajax event="change" 
        update="localizacaoPorLotacao" />       
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione a lotação" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{itemQuadroVagasBean.listarLotacoes()}" 
        var="lotacao"
        itemLabel="#{lotacao.formatarLocalizacao()}" />                                                             
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need event:

```
<p:ajax update="localizacaoPorLotacao" event="change"/>
```

Comment: Added, but nothing happened. :(

Comment: @Rafael Simonelli Is setter for #{itemBean.lotacao} called?

Comment: @RafaelSimonelli Did you put your components inside an `h:form`?

Comment: @Multisync as weird as it may seem... no! :(

Comment: I'll debug the cause of the setter not being called

Comment: Debuggin right now why isn't this specific setter working. All others seem to be in order. Any thoughts? :)

Comment: @Rafael Simonelli <p:ajax update="@this localizacaoPorLotacao" process="@this" event="change"/>

Comment: @Rafael Simonelli Or maybe jsf doesn't think you've changed anything. Try to add listener and handle the changes there